# Alguien sabe porque esta sentencia en js me arroja true?

Tags: javascript

no tengo la mínima idea, de porque esta resultado me esta arrojando verdadero, se supone que el total de descuento que vale 500 es menor al subtotal que vale 1063, pero por alguna razón la comparación me esta dando true, lo cual no es correcto, que di@blos estoy haciendo mal?

El codigo de validacion es este

```
        var td = 0;
        td=$('#TotalDiscount').val();

        var st = 0;
        st = $('#SubTotal').val();


        if ( td > st   )
        {
            alert("El monto cubierto no puede ser mayor al monto generado por la factura");
            $("#TotalDiscount").val("0.00");
            $("#CoverPercent").val("0.00");
            return;
        }
```

Este es el resultado que me esta arrojando true, donde incluso probando el parseo de los objetos me esta arrojando true.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el codigo en texto porfavor? Nos ayudará a apoyarte mejor en tu problema.

Comment: Claro, ya esta, puedes checar

Comment: Haciendo este también te falla? lo has probado? parseFloat(td) > parseFloat(st)

Comment: Quitandole el tofixed dentro de la comparación de prueba y parseando el td y el st funciono nitido,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eso se debe a que la función `toFixed()` devuelve un string para evitar problemas con decimales grandes (simplificando mucho la explicación).

Para poder compararlos vas a tener que volver a pasar los valores por el `parseFloat()`